# Error Importing Image into React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `images` folder with one image `stock.jpg` in it. When I try to import it into my Movie component with `import {stock} from '../images/stock.jpg'` I get an error `Attempted import error: 'stock' is not exported from '../images/stock.jpg'`. The file path in the import looks fine to me, here's my directory structure [image: directory structure]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't used named imports for static assets. Try something like `import stock from '../images/stock.jpg'` instead

Comment: Mind explaining why not? It's strange because many other S.O posts show examples of using named exports.

Comment: Because is a static asset. You don't have JS code inside the JPEG exporting a `stock` symbol or any other symbol for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try again to export `without {}`

```js
import ImageJPG from "../images/stock.jpg";
```

If it is `svg`

```js
import {ReactComponent as ImageSVG} from "../images/stock.svg"
```

Comment: Why don't named exports work?

Comment: `default export`